# JQuery select from options by text

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I have the following html:

```
<select class="select optional form-control" id="search_form_handover_location" name="search_form[handover_location]"><option value="">Wybierz miejsce odbioru</
    <option value="Gdańsk">Gdańsk</option>
    <option value="Gdańsk">Gdańsk, Lotnisko</option>
    <option value="Ożarowice">Katowice, Lotnisko</option>
</select>    
<select class="select optional form-control" id="search_form_return_location" name="search_form[return_location]"><option value="">Wybierz miejsce zwrotu</option>
      <option value="Gdańsk">Gdańsk</option>
      <option value="Gdańsk">Gdańsk, Lotnisko</option>
      <option value="Ożarowice">Katowice, Lotnisko</option>
</select>
```

In my application I'm using JQuery to autocomplete this second select. So when you in the first select choose "Gdańsk" it will also select it in second select. My coffeescript code for this looks like this:

```
$ ->
  $('#search_form_handover_location').change ->
    location = $("option:selected", this).val()
    $('#search_form_return_location').val(location)
```

Now I do this thing by using value of each option. But now I want to do this by using not value but text. So when in first select you choose "Gdańsk, Lotnisko" it will auto choose in second select option with the same text. Is there any possibilty to solve my problem?

Comment: you have the same value for first and second options, so when you choose first or second option in first dropdown, it will always choose the first option in your second dropdown. If that's what your problem is kindly change the values and try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : get text form first dropdown and find it in second dropdown.

```
$ ->
  $('#search_form_handover_location').change ->
     locationTxt = $("option:selected", this).text();

        $('#search_form_return_location option').each(function(){
           if($(this).text()==locationTxt)
               $(this).prop('selected',true);
           else
               $(this).removeProp('selected'); 
       });
```

Comment: Thank's for help. But unfortunately this code doesn't work as I want. Sometimes it search properly, sometimes not. I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: @MateuszUrbański, do you check browser console? do you find any error?

Comment: @MateuszUrbański, this is working fine for me. See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pcoKw

Comment: This is not working properly. Please select once all of the options from first select and then try this again, you will see that the second select is not updating.

Comment: which browser you are using? I have tried the same as you said but working properly on chrome.

Comment: Oh in Chrome works great but in Firefox it crashes. I use Firefox. I don't have any idea why it crash in Firefox...

Comment: @MateuszUrbański, It is working now. Just use .prop instead of .attr and removing previously selected option in else part. see this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/uzDcm. Tested on firefox.

Answer (score 3):

You can get text with this line, Do with it what you want...

```
$("#search_form_handover_location:selected").text();
```

Comment: Thank's for reply. I know that i can get text with "text" method. But now I don't know how in second select menu select proper option by this text.

Comment: For that try this : `$('#search_form_return_location').find('option[text="your text here"]').attr('selected',true);`. I have not tried this but may be it will work for you...

Answer (score 1):

```
var location=$("#search_form_handover_location:selected").text();

$("#search_form_return_location option").filter(function() {
    //may want to use $.trim in here
    return $(this).text() == location; 
}).attr('selected', true);
```

Comment: This code works almost properly but it sometimes select wrong things. I don't know why.

Comment: @MateuszUrbański, which jquery version are you using? If you are using v1.6+ jquery version, use 'prop' instead 'attr'.

Comment: I think I know where is the problem. When I change selected option in first select it is selecting from second select and add attribute :selected to this option. And this attribute cause the problem. When option from second select has this attribute "selected" it not works properly. Did you know how to solve this problem?